# Unable to solve particular solution for non homogeneous second order diff. eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The book I'm following jumps many "obvious" steps and sometimes I can't follow up. I have the following non homogenous equation. However I'm unable to find the particular solution since I have so many unknowns and can't simplify. I tired factoring out (A and B) or (sin x and cos x) but that didn't help eaither. How sould I proceed with this? Also I'm unsure if my trial solution $y_p(x) = Axcos(x) + Bx sin(x)$ is correct.

[image]

Small note: there should be a $c_1$ before $cos 10 x $ at line 3.

Comment: Someone suggested that I should try:$y_p(x)=A\,cos(10x)+B\,sin(10x)$
I tried that and everything cancelled out in the left hand side. I got $-A\,cos(10x)-B\,sin(10x)+A\,cos(10x)+B\,sin(10x)=sin(10x)+cos(10x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+100y=100(\sin 10x+\cos 10x) \implies\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=50\sqrt{2}\sin \left(10x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$

**C.F.**

$y_c=A \cos 10x +B \sin 10x$

**P.I**

$y_p=v_1(x)\cos 10x +v_2(x)\sin 10x$

$\therefore v_1=-\dfrac{1}{100\sqrt{2}}\dfrac{\sin 10x\sin \left(10x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\left \lvert \begin{matrix}\cos 10x & \sin 10x \\-\sin 10x & \cos 10x  \\              \end{matrix}\right\rvert}
=-\dfrac{1}{100\sqrt{2}}\sin 10x\sin \left(10x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$

$\therefore v_2=\dfrac{1}{100\sqrt{2}}\dfrac{\cos 10x\sin \left(10x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\left \lvert \begin{matrix}\cos 10x & \sin 10x \\-\sin 10x & \cos 10x  \\              \end{matrix}\right\rvert}
=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos 10x\sin \left(10x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$